# Need to show/hide images based on wrapping div's data-group

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I am needing to show color swatches based on the dynamically pulled data-group values. Sometimes the data-group will include all 3 swatches (silver, rose and gold) and sometimes it will only include one. I can't hardcode in display:none since it's dynamic. The images I am needing to show/hide are the ones with the silver, rose and gold classes. Let me know if I need to further clarify.

Here is my staging link for context: http://cerimani-new.webflow.io/our-collections/view-all

```
<a href="/our-collection/examplelink">
<div data-group="silver rose" class="product">
  <img src="/exampleimg.jpg" />

      <div class="product-listing-details">
        <h2 class="product-listing-hdr">Item Name</h2>
        <p class="product-listing-price">$450</p>

        <img class="silver" src="https://exampleimg.png" />
        <img class="rose" src="https://exampleimg.png" />
        <img class="gold" src="https://exampleimg.png" />

      </div>

</div>
</a>
```

Comment: In the above html, div has two `data-group` value. So which image should show?

Comment: The images that have the same class as the data-group value should show.

Answer (score 0):

This should be something to get you started.  It will hide all irrelevant and then only show the ones that pertain to the search. Comment if you need more help.

```js
$("[show-class]").click(function () {
  $(".shoppingImage").hide()
  $("." + $(this).attr("show-class")).show();
});

//for on page laod:

url = new URL(window.location.href);
searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
$("[show-class=" + searchParams.get('show') + "]").click();
```

```css
img {
  width:100px;
}

[show-class] {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-group="silver rose" class="product">
  <img src="/exampleimg.jpg" />
  
  Only show:
  <ul>
    <li show-class="rose">Rose</li>
    <li show-class="silver">Silver</li>
    <li show-class="gold">Gold</li>
  </ul>

      <div class="product-listing-details">
        <h2 class="product-listing-hdr">Item Name</h2>
        <p class="product-listing-price">$450</p>

        <img class="shoppingImage silver" src="https://ak1.ostkcdn.com/images/products/9576615/ICZ-Stonez-Sterling-Silver-2-7-8ct-TGW-Cubic-Zirconia-Princess-Bridal-Engagement-Ring-Set-a06f1f4b-a973-4bf4-bdb8-e10b90946f2a_600.jpg" />
        <img class="shoppingImage rose" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/27/1e/18/271e18e5c0c63651b77cfe11a7ad8e22.jpg" />
        <img class="shoppingImage gold" src="http://www.cartier.com/content/dam/rcq/car/63/69/78/636978.png.scale.314.high.png" />

      </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I am very new to javascript so I'm not sure this is what I need exactly. Don't need to tie it to the filters or a search, just need to automatically show or hide based on the wrapping div's data-group. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding something, I'm as new to js as it gets :-/

Comment: I don't want the user to have to click anything, just want it to show or hide based on the values on load. Should not require user interaction at all.

Comment: Are you using get parameters in PHP?

Comment: No, I am building the site in Webflow so am somewhat limited.

Comment: Then just use jQuery to filter it, it will look better in the end.

Comment: I would but I don't know how to go about that.

Comment: Either way, if you are trying to dynamically remove elements, you'll **have** to use JavaScript, and trust me JavaScript with the jQuery library is SO much easier.  And I gave you an example to work with.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought the example was based on the fact that you would have to click something in order to get it to work. I am so lost I may try to just pay someone to do this.

Comment: I added some JavaScript, so now if a user visits example.com/shop.php?**show**=gold, it will now display the correct items.  Whatever you put after show will show on the first page load.   If you could upvote/mark as solution, that helps a lot.

Comment: I upvoted it but my rep is apparently too low to count :-(

Comment: Just click the green checkbox next to it to select it as the answer, that'll be great too.

Comment: I can't mark as a solution because we aren't quite on the same page as to  what I'm needing. Sorry. I need all products to load each swatch combo based on that products parent div's data-group without having to click anything or change the url.

Comment: Honestly, this website isn't designed to write code for you or to teach you how to program.  It is meant for people who have written code and are looking for a bit of help getting it working properly...  And I honestly can't keep guessing as to what you want.  Accept the solution if you want.

Comment: I know html, php, css and only enough javascript to get myself in trouble. I'm teaching myself now but I have a client who added this new feature request and wants it done quickly so I was at a loss. I figured it would be an easy fix but I guess not. I tried searching through past posts but couldn't find something similar enough to my situation so I guess I apologize for posting my question. Thought my explanation made sense but I'm sorry we weren't able to get on the same page.